# Google apps marketplace - test app - admin workflow vs individual workflow

Tags: testing, workflow, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to build a prototype for one of our customers. We have one intermediate step during install.

I want to show them the workflow of how the end customer admins will see the app in marketplace, follow the steps of install and then it will show up in the top box.

The regular users for that domain can then click on that icon to initiate the app workflow.

In the previous version of marketplace sdk, I could do this easily.

But in the current version, I don't see the option to add the manifest. Can't demo app in marketplace.

There is only one button test install flow. Which actually takes me to the app url instead of install url.

Is that the only way to demo a complete test workflow?

Comment: You can configure a "Setup URL" in the listing, which is presented to the admin after the installation has completed. If you have previously tested the install flow, first uninstall the application from the domain before testing it again.

Comment: @EricKoleda The setup URL is kind of not working for me now. The app is already installed before the admin hits setup page. I want the app to be not installed if they do not have an account with us.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible in the new Marketplace. The setup URL is optionally visited by the admin. Instead, you can show an error screen to users that try to use the app before the admin has finished the setup.